# Why do I get a syntax error if I run this in the console? {} === {}

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

In the chromium console I run `{} === {}` and I get a Syntax error, unexpected '==='.

If I however wrap this in parens, like `({} === {})` then I get `false`, what I'd expect.

Is an object literal, in the first position, confused with a code block or something?

Comment: Yes, without the parentheses it's a statement, not an expression, so it tries to interpret the first pair of curly brackets as an empty code block.

Comment: Seems it needs functions to be executed in console. What about chrome console or Firefox's console.

Comment: Your guess is correct. The Chromium console lets you run arbitrary statements, not just evaluate expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a surrounding parenthesis, `{}` would be considered as an empty [`code block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) in javascript. `=` followed by a `code block` would be an invalid syntax. That is why you are seeing an error there.

If you wrap it inside of a parenthesis like `({} === {})`, then it would be considered as an `expression` and it will be evaluated to false as both are referencing two different objects.

The following example may give you a clear picture about it,

```
{ var x = 5; console.log(x); } == 2
// will throw the same error that you are facing.
```