# Why does commuting the arguments of == in a console change the output?

Tags: javascript, equals-operator, browser-console

If I open my browser console (tested in Chrome/Firefox) and type:

```
null == {}
```

I get:

> false

However, if I commute both arguments to the `==` operator and instead type:

```
{} == null
```

I get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==

Image:

[image]

- **Why does this happen?**
- Why does this only happen in a console and not when the browser executes a script within an HTML page?

**EDIT:**

While [question 35812626](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812616/why-do-i-get-a-syntax-error-if-i-run-this-in-the-console) addresses this and explains the cause as JS parsing the `{}` as a code block, it uses the triple equals (strict comparison) operator `===`, not the double equals `==`. As a user points out below, a code block can definitely be followed by `==` without causing a syntax error:

```
{} == {} // false
```

How come this works and my example does not?

Comment: Ok , what is the practically reason to use {} == anything ?

Answer (score 4):

I think its because the interpreter interprets `{}` as a block of code not as an object.

so your code `{} == null` turns out to be a block start and end then a statement starts with `==` which is definitely a syntax error.

but if you can try `({} == null)` I think it should run fine.

and as pointed out by @dhaker `{}=={}` returning `false` not an error.

and i found there are few scenario returning result and few getting error.

following are getting error:

```
{}==null //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==
{}==1 //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==
{}==0 //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==
{}==true //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==
{}==false //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==
{}==true //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==
{}=='' //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==
{}=='hi' //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==
{}==(new Object) //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==
```

following are returning result without an error:

```
{}=={} //false
{}==function(){} //false
```

so i guess it has something to do with how the Javascript is compiled or interpreted by the browsers.

for much detailed answer please check following answer.

[Odd behaviour of comparison of object literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50989247/odd-behaviour-of-comparison-of-object-literals/50989638#50989638)

Comment: Why `{}=={}` returning `false` , if your logic is correct ?.

Comment: @dhaker the question was originally about the error its getting, but then it has been updated couple of times. i'll check your concern though.

Comment: Its not about question its about your explanation, which seems to be inconsistent - **Its because the interpreter interprets {} as a block of code not as an object**.

Comment: @dhaker i thought like that because if you execute `{};=={}` it gets the same error as `{}==null`. the semicolon terminated the block and it gets the same error. so it leads me to think that an statement is trying to start with `==` and getting the error.

Comment: @dhaker but yes your concern is a valid one and i may be wrong (i may be missing something)

Comment: Got a valid answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50989247/odd-behaviour-of-comparison-of-object-literals/50989638#50989638

Answer (score 3):

I tested on safari this is not true.

null is primitive variable and null can be on left side.

But {} for javaScript is namespace. Used for creating global object.

Answer is simple: there is no sense for using {} with equality operators.

**Updated :**

It is a so clear :

Anything in javascript what comes with { have no ***assignment*** .

Let try to say :

{ x : null }

and what you will get ?

Nothing . Can you access this object again ? No.

```js
console.log( null == {} );

console.log( {} == null );

console.log( null === {} );

console.log( {} === null );

// Also 

var object1 = {'key': 'value'}
var object2 = {'key': 'value'};
console.log(object1 === object2); //false

console.log({} === {}); //false

console.log({} == {}); //false

({}) == null; // little hack ;) false

// {} == null; syntax error !

 (typeof {}) == (typeof {});
 
 var A = {};
 var B = {};
 (typeof A) === (typeof B);

// console.log( (A instanceof "object" ) );
console.log( typeof A );

// This is only correct 
console.log(typeof A === typeof B)
console.log(typeof {} === typeof {})
```

**I try this stupid thing :**

> {'test':0}.hasOwnProperty('test')

and i get same staff ( syntaxError ) . Don't use it like that!

Comment: To expand on that,I feel like it should be pointed out as to why it makes no sense to compare - **null in javascript literally means non-existent and can't truly be evaluated as it's not an indentifier of a property**. If you want to consider a variable as undefined, then do precisely that and use the `undefined` keyword isntead! More info on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null)

Comment: `I tested on safari this is not true.` Did you try this without the `console.log` around it? Because that does make a difference.

Comment: `{}=={}` this is returning false, it means we can compare `{}` this with others

Comment: if you ask me this {}=={} code no sense. There is a methods for comparing objects but trick is when you just say {} it is a represent namespace but actually is nothing (  Inus Saha - syntax error ). If you say var myObject = {}; then myObject is 'object' empty but regular.

Comment: First you said - **there is no sense for using {} with equality operators.**. Now you are saying -  **{}=={} code no sense**. What is sense then ?. I am trying to understand logic behind it but could not get.