# Why is this JavaScript not interpreted as a code block when semi-colon is used?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, syntax, destructuring, object-destructuring

In `Chrome` version `^72` if I run the following `JavaScript` there are no errors.

```
{ prop: p } = { prop: 'prop' }
>> { prop: 'prop' }
```

So the line of code is interpreted as an expression statement, unexpectedly.

But if I run the same code with a semi-colon at the end it runs as expected.

```
{ prop: p } = { prop: 'prop' };
>> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

This is expected since the initial `{` tells the `JavaScript` engine that it is a code block unless we disambiguate with parentheses.

Why does this occur with the semi-colon but not without it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does this occur with the semi-colon but not without it?

Chrome uses a very simple test to see whether a line is an object literal or not: Does the line start with a `{` and end with a `}`? If yes, the line is evaluated as an **expression**.

`{ prop: p } = { prop: 'prop' }` passes that test, but `{ prop: p } = { prop: 'prop' };` does not.

---

See [Odd behaviour of comparison of object literals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50989247/218196) for more info (different input, same reason).