# javascript Unary plus between brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

1.`{}+[]` gives `0`

2.`[]+{}` gives `[object  object]` I know how 1 and 2 comes but

3.`{}+[]+{}` gives `[object  object][object  object]`

how shouldn't it be `0[object  object]`?

Comment: Where is the code executed?

Comment: Code is executed in Chrome REPL.

Comment: @mplungjan: I think these are all wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/q/36438034/218196 is the right duplicate.

Comment: Chrome uses a simple heuristic and evaluates a line that starts with `{` and ends with `}` as an expression. Therefore both `{}` in `{}+[]+{}` are evaluated as objects an object, whereas the `{}` in `{}+[]` is a block.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438034/why-is-no-longer-nan-in-chrome-console . The expression is slightly different, but the reason/answer is the same.

Comment: Well done @FelixKling - It was a dupe of something and the rest are relevant to show type coercion

Comment: To be absolutely clear: You will get `0[object  object]` in other environments (e.g. Firefox). It's just the Chrome console that interprets `{}+[]+{}` as if you write `({}+[]+{})`.

Comment: Other related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53712304/218196, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50989247/218196

Answer (score 0):

When you use `console.log`, it executes `toString` - which when using `{} + []`, gives `[object Object]`.

```js
console.log({} + []);
```

(Note: simply placing `{} + []` into the Developer Tools console gives `0`, because `toString` is not called).

That's why this yields `[object Object][object Object]`:

```js
console.log({} + [] + {});
```

Because you're adding an object (formed from `{} + []`) to another object, and because you're using the `+` concatenation operator, this forces `toString` - therefore, you're adding `[objectObject]` and `[object Object]`, yielding `[object Object][object Object]`.

Note: The above all are on Chrome. In Firefox and potentially others, they work differently, which is why some things in your question are different.

Comment: `({}+[])` this will `[object object]` why

Comment: what is the difference between `({}+[])` vs `{}+[]` vs `console.log({}+[])`

Comment: Because in `console.log`, it calls `toString`.

Comment: ok but what about `({}+[])` it is also calling `toString()`

Comment: That's because of the `()`

Comment: Writing in Chrome console without `console.log` gives you a different answer because it's not calling `toString`. `console.log` calls `toString`, which on an object yields `[object Object]`.

Comment: Since you are already saying that `console.log` is different than having `{} + []` on its own, how can you say that their information is wrong? They are simply executing their code differently.

Comment: I'm sorry @FelixKling, I know what you're saying, I just don't know how to phrase it correctly - how should I do so?

Comment: @FelixKling I edited my answer, is it better now?

Comment: While you are explaining what `{} + [] + {}` results in when evaluated as expression, the missing piece is why `{} + [] + {}` is evaluated as expression in the first place. In Firefox the same code yields `"0[object Object]"`, which shows that is evaluated differently (and correctly btw).

Comment: I don't know why that is - it works in Firefox (just tested myself) but works differently in Chrome (gives `[object Object][object Object]`). I'll put that in my answer.

Comment: Well, that's what the question is about (kind of) ;) The answer is in the duplicate.